# Why does Renaming dataframe columns with inplace = True trigger the setting with copy warning?

Tags: python, pandas

The dataframe `kidsSingleHeads94_98` is created from the dataframe `mydata94_98`. The `.is_copy` attribute of `kidsSingleHeads94_98` shows a weak reference to `mydata94_98`.

```
>>> kidsSingleHeads94_98.is_copy
<weakref at 0x000000010ECE0EF8; to 'DataFrame' at 0x000000010DCDE048>
>>> hex(id(mydata94_98))
'0x10dcde048'
```

This `.rename` operation with `inplace = True` triggers the `SettingWithCopy` warning and I'm not sure why that's the case. I was under the impression that `inplace = True` means you are *not* creating a copy of the underlying dataframe being manipulated, but are operating ... inplace ...

```
kidsSingleHeads.rename( columns = { "Gender":"GenderChild", 
                                    "Age":"AgeChild", 
                                    "EducationYears":"EducationYearsChild" }, inplace = True )
pandas.core.common.SettingWithCopyError:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

I've been struggling to understand the difference between views and copies. I understand that setting on a view of a dataframe will modify it while setting on a copy of it will not.

From Wes McKinney's **Python for Data Analysis** pg. 114

> The column returned when indexing a DataFrame is a *view* on the underlying data, not a copy. Thus, any in-place modifications to the Series will be reflected in the DataFrame. The column can be explicitly copied using the Series' **copy** method.

I think sub-setting a dataframe and setting values to something else with that subset can create copies which can be costly because of the extra effort of writing new data to memory? I'm not clear on that.

**NOTE**

I set `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = 'raise'` so python would raise an exception and crash the program. I used the utilized the traceback in the error message in order to find exactly which command was trigger the `SettingWithCopy` issue. The default setting is to `'warn'`.

Comment: `kidsSingleHeads94_98` being still linked to `mydata94_98` leads to the warning. Modifying `kidsSingleHeads94_98` leads to an indirect modification of `mydata94_98`. That's what the copy warning is about; not because `kidsSingleHeads94_98` is being changed in place.

Comment: The column names in `mydata94_98` are still the same

Comment: `mydata94_98` may not change at all because of the reference between `mydata94_98` and `kidsSingleHeads94_98` is a `weakref`. Since `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment` is set to 'warn', then the modification may be made to the second dataframe without affecting the first.

Answer (score 0):

you should create kidsSingleHeads94_98 using copy() function to avoid this warning.